# How do I prevent the account opened with Firebase Auth from being closed?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am preparing an application and this application has a login and registration system. The user's data will be kept on Firebase.

But there is a problem with this application. Every time the user opens the application, that login or register screen will come again. As a matter of fact, this will be very annoying and the user will be bored.

I want the user to log in or register the first time she opens the application, and then every time she opens the application, the account is open.

How should I go about this? How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: Can you share your code? Every time appsopens, you can check if user is logged on already

Answer (score 2):

You simply do a check if the user is already signed in.

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users):

```
var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

if (user != null) {
   // user is logged in
   return app();
}
// otherwise, show login/register
return splashScreen();
```

You can also listen with [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) (best for your use case)

Comment: So how long is this session? For example, let's say the user logged in and opened the application again 3 days later. Will the account still remain open?

Comment: It is hard to tell how long but it is possible that the auth state will persist from what I experience. That is why you always check if the user is still signed in if necessary.

Comment: The user credentials are automatically persisted and restored by the Firebase SDK. So in most cases the session never expires, and the user will never have to sign in again. The only time that is different is in cases like where you disable the account, their password is changed from another device, and things like that.